# How can I reclassify a raster to floating point values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, floating-point

I have a raster of landuse values that I need to reclassify into pollution concentration values. I have the pollution values in a separate table. They are decimal values (ex. 0.0056), and my landuse values are integers 1 through 6. I have a table mapping the landuse values to the pollution values.

I tried using the Reclass By Table tool, setting my pollution values as the "Output value field", but the tool description says that this field must be an integer field. **How can I reclassify the values into decimal values?** I feel like I must be missing a much easier, alternate solution.

My goal is to have a pollution concentration raster that I can use later in further calculations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Make sure your raster of landuse values has an [attribute table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m2000000)
2. [Add a join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_Join/001700000064000000/) between landuse attribute table and pollution concentration table
3. Use the [Lookup (Reclass)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Lookup/009z000000sn000000/) tool to create a new raster from the landuse raster with the values from the joined pollution concentration field.

Comment: Why is step 3 needed? Can you not just create a new raster from the concentration values obtained in 2?  (One used to be able to do that in older versions of Spatial Analyst.)

Comment: @whuber Because the old dot notation (raster.attribute) syntax that ESRI supported for years has been dropped as of ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a simple way: multiply your concentrations by 10000 (or other value), to get all values as integers. Then you reclassify the raster. This will output a raster of type integer, so convert it to floating point using the float function. Then just divide output raster by the same 10000 using Raster calculator.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with complex conditional statement in the raster calculator. For example, I have a raster with FIDs of 0, 1, 2, and 3, and associated float values for each class. The expression looked like this:

```
Con("n_scene" == 0,0.04,Con("n_scene" == 1,0.13648,Con("n_scene" == 2,0.10343,Con("n_scene" == 3,0.0369))))
```